# Android attaching adapter to RecyclerView

Tags: android

after read many posts like with this error i cant fix that. after running android application i get this error:

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
```

My code:

```
private LatestNewsAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void parse_latest_news(String result, int code) {
    set_reload_status(false);
    if (code != 100) {
        Utils.handle_error_codes(base_activity, code);
    } else {
        ArrayList<LatestNewsModel> data = LatestNewsXMLParser.parse_user_xml_data(result);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(base_activity);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);

        adapter = new LatestNewsAdapter(data, base_activity);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your `RecyclerView` not attach the adapter at all? It just means that your data is not yet ready to be binded since it looks like you're setting it from a callback method. If you want to avoid the message completely then first set an empty adapter

Comment: is your okey code = 100 ?

Comment: @YasinKaçmaz yes sir.

Comment: this is not a solution maybe , but can try declare your adapter in there too like linearlayoutmanager . I think you cant fill your adapter so its empty and then recycler view have no adapter i think.